# Setting enum flags by string (in any order)

Tags: c#, enum

I want to set flags which are given in string representation in any order. And it is intimidating, because you have to check like 2^3 possible options in my occassion. I was just wondering is there any better way to do that than just simple brute-force. Any optimization and readability improvment would be great. This is my code:

```
[Flags]
public enum salaryFeatures
{
Children = 1,
Graduate = 2,
Disability = 4
}

class Program
{

public static void Main()
{
    string Employee = "10023 Mark Male 6.7 70 30 20 Children Graduate";
    salaryFeatures f;
    f = GetFeaturesByString(Employee);
}

public static salaryFeatures GetFeaturesByString(string fields)
{
    bool children = false;
    bool graduate = false;
    bool disability = false;
    salaryFeatures features = new salaryFeatures();

    if (fields.ToLower().Contains("children")) children = true;
    if (fields.ToLower().Contains("graduate")) graduate = true;
    if (fields.ToLower().Contains("disability")) disability = true;

    if (children && graduate && disability)
    {
        return features = salaryFeatures.Children | salaryFeatures.Disability | salaryFeatures.Graduate;
    }
    if (children && graduate)
    {
        return features = salaryFeatures.Children | salaryFeatures.Graduate;
    }
    if (children && disability)
    {
        return features = salaryFeatures.Children | salaryFeatures.Disability;
    }
    if (children)
    {
        return features = salaryFeatures.Children;
    }
    if (graduate && disability)
    {
        return features = salaryFeatures.Graduate | salaryFeatures.Disability;
    }
    if (graduate)
    {
        return features = salaryFeatures.Graduate;
    }
    if (disability)
    {
        return features = salaryFeatures.Disability;
    }
    return features;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my take on your code

```
[Flags]
public enum SalaryFeatures
{
  None= 0,
  Children = 1,
  Graduate = 2,
  Disability = 4
}

class Program
{

  public static void Main()
  {
    string Employee = "10023 Mark Male 6.7 70 30 20 Children Graduate";
    SalaryFeatures f;
    f = GetFeaturesByString(Employee);
    // f.Dump(); //LinqPad only
  }

  public static SalaryFeatures GetFeaturesByString(string fields)
  {
    SalaryFeatures features = SalaryFeatures.None;

    if (fields.IndexOf("children", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) features |= SalaryFeatures.Children;
    if (fields.IndexOf("graduate", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) features |= SalaryFeatures.Graduate;
    if (fields.IndexOf("disability", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) features |= SalaryFeatures.Disability;

    return features;
  }
}
```

First of the definition of your Enumeration is not complete. You need to define a None value for it

> Use None as the name of the flag enumerated constant whose value is
>   zero. You cannot use the None enumerated constant in a bitwise AND
>   operation to test for a flag because the result is always zero.
>   However, you can perform a logical, not a bitwise, comparison between
>   the numeric value and the None enumerated constant to determine
>   whether any bits in the numeric value are set.

See also the [Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) when defining a Flags enum. I also change the naming of the enum to PascalCase (`SalaryFeatures`).

After that I have improved your method `GetFeaturesByString` to use bitwise **OR** to combine the values depending on the values that are found in your string. I also use the method `IndexOf(string, StringComparison)` to check if the search string exists in the source string, instead of using `ToLower()` and `Contains()`.

Comment: Can you say why you use StringComparison instead of contains()? Is it faster or just more appropriate somehow?

Comment: @Unknown I want to avoid the call to ToLower() cause you are only interested if the string is present (ignoring casing) in the source string. So I choose IndexOf with StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase. This returns a value greater than or equal 0 if the string was found.

Answer (score 3):

It would be a good idea to extract the salary features from the string before you start processing them. You should put this in method (extension?) that specializes in this.

```
var text = "10023 Mark Male 6.7 70 30 20 Children Graduate";
var fieldNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof(salaryFeatures)).Where(n => text.IndexOf(n) >= 0);
```

Now after having found the fields you can parse them in another method, ignore the case and build the flags with linq's `Aggregate` extension:

```
var salaryFeatures = fieldNames.Aggregate(SalaryFeatures.None, (result, next) 
    => result |= (SalaryFeatures)Enum.Parse(typeof(SalaryFeatures), next, true));
```

- use the `Aggregate` extension to concatenate the flags
- use the `ignoreCase = true`
- the `salaryFeatures` should actually be named with PascalCase `SalaryFeatures`
- if you defined one additional flag `None` you could use it instead of `(salaryFeatures)0`

---

Both these changes will allow you to add more flags in future without modifying those methods.

Comment: This looks reasonable, since bit confusing. I have to take some time to understand this completely, anyway, thank you!

Comment: Enum.Parse() can understand a comma separated string e.g Enum.Parse(typeof(SalaryFeatures), string.Join(",", fieldNames), true)

Comment: @AlanT cool, I didn't know that. Then there is no need for the `Aggregate`.

Comment: In my experience attempts to map `string` values to `Enum` using `Parse` method eventually backfire due to various reasons: localization,  changes in format/protocol, etc. So I tend to just manually map the values straight away. I feel like the only situation where parsing is the best option, is if those strings are actually produced by `SalaryFeatures.ToString()` call in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another variant using the Aggregate extension method:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/7RrGTE

```
[Flags]
public enum SalaryFeatures
{
    None = 0,
    Children = 1,
    Graduate = 2,
    Disability = 4
}

//...

    var employee = "Mark: Disability Male with Children"; 
    var features =
        Enumerable.
        Range(0, Enum.GetValues(typeof(SalaryFeatures)).Length - 1).
        Aggregate
        (
            SalaryFeatures.None,
            (f, b) =>
                employee.
                Contains(
                ((SalaryFeatures)(1 << b)).
                ToString()) ?
                f | (SalaryFeatures)(1 << b)
                :
                f
        );
    var f = (int)features;
    Console.WriteLine(f); // expected: 5
```

(where "Length - 1" is to account for the presence of SalaryFeatures.None)